# Migrate Mutliple Columns to Single Column Object Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following columns: user_address, user_city, user_state, and user_zip.

I have created a new column that has a custom object datatype:

```
CREATE TYPE ADDRESS_ADT AS OBJECT (
  address VARCHAR2(255),
  city VARCHAR2(20),
  state  CHAR(2),
  zip VARCHAR2(20)
);
ALTER TABLE 
  USERS
ADD (
  ADDRESS ADDRESS_ADT
);
```

I want to write a PL/SQL Unnamed procedure to migrate addresses to this new single column but am not sure how to approach it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a cursor, loop through the table
2. Read into the cursor
3. Build your `ADDRESS_ADT` object
4. Update the table

Something like this:

```
declare
    cursor users_cur is 
        select rowid, street_address as address, city, state, zip
        from users;
    type users_aat is table of users_cur%ROWTYPE index by pls_integer;
    l_users users_aat;
    l_address_adt address_adt;
begin
    open users_cur;
    loop
        fetch users_cur bulk collect into l_users limit 100;

        for i in 1..l_users.count
        loop
            l_address_adt := address_adt(
                l_users(i).address,
                l_users(i).city,
                l_users(i).state,
                l_users(i).zip
            );

            update users set address = l_address_adt
            where rowid = l_users(i).rowid;
        end loop;
        exit when l_users.count < 100;
    end loop;
    commit;
    close users_cur;
end;
/
```